# Http request (GET) timeout sometimes and I want to find the cause

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, http-headers, postman

I am developing an iOS app that makes an API request to my server hosted in Heroku.
In my slow internet connection environment, the API request (via Http Get) sometimes results in a timeout. The response time is usually 2000 ms if not timing out.

By "sometimes", I mean about one in 10 requests times out (I do not get any meaningful error code).

I also tested this timeout with 2 devices. When one device is waiting for the server to respond for longer than 2000 ms, I use another device to call the api, to which the server responds normally. But the first device still results in a timeout.

I am not quite sure what is to blame here. My internet connection? My api server on Heroku? I also tested this timeout on Postman and got the same results.

PS. I am based out of Bangkok. The ISP with which I experience the most timeouts is True Broadband.

Any and all advice is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

PPS. In response to comments warning that the question is too broad: Let's ask it this way.  If our api calls randomly time out, how can we detect whether it is due to a slow internet connection, or if the fault lies in our own server (or something else)?

Comment: what are you using to call your api ???? third party or native

Comment: Native. But the timeout is not just inside the app. It happens when I used Postman to call also

Comment: so you should change your server settings or move your server to aws(amazon web services)

Comment: What kind of heroku instance are you using?

Comment: If it is one specific request that is timing out can you post the code being run with that request?

Comment: @spacepotato It is not one specific request. The timeout happens to all of my request but just like I explained not everytime

Comment: @HieuPham We are using performance plan and paid around $600 per month to Heroku